# Finding the nth term of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was asked to find the $n^{th}$ term of the geometric sequence provided below:

$$\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{1}{5}, \frac{6}{125}, -\frac{7}{625}, ...$$

I have no clue

Comment: Do you understand what a geometric sequence is?

Comment: Yes, I have the formula for geometric sequences nth term, but i have to find the r (ratio)

Comment: So you look at the ratio and you find it is $-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{6}{25},-\frac{7}{30}$ which does not look remotely like a geometric sequence, so you check carefully to make sure you have copied the question down correctly!

Comment: The only pattern I can see is that those ratios are $-\frac{5}{20},-\frac{6}{25},-\frac{7}{30}$.

Comment: What makes you think it is a geometric sequence? Were you simply asked to find the $n$th term of the "following sequence"?

Comment: But if that pattern persists then the $n$th term would be $(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+3}{5^n}$

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found an answer to this;

I double check the question, and it is the same one.

The tricky part, is we got to realize that:

$$\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{1}{5}, \frac{6}{125}, -\frac{7}{625}, ...$$

Starting at the numerator;
$$4,1,6,7, ...$$
So we know that the numerator part is increasing somehow.

Now looking at the denominator we can say that;
$$5^1, 5^1, 5^3, 5^4, ...$$
So the denominator's power is increasing as $n$ increases.

But what about the second term, it always messes our prediction. What we can do about it, is realizing that the numerator should be 5 and denominator should be 25.

If we multiply that fraction by 5, we get $-\frac{5}{25}$ which is exactly true, and matches our prediction. (The trick that they simplified the second term to confuse us).

So now we have;

$$\frac{4}{5}, -\frac{5}{25}, \frac{6}{125}, -\frac{7}{625}, ...$$

It is easy now, we can write the $n^{th}$ term without sign change first;

$$\frac{n+3}{5^n}$$

Now for the sign change;

$$(-1)^{n+1} \; {{n+3}\over{5^n}}$$

Which is our final answer ($n^{th}$ term) for this Sequence.